# How to make animations smoother in low refresh rate display android device?

Tags: android

this question is a general question.I just wanted to know if there is any way through.I am having a very low refresh rate display android device due to which all the animations are getting lagged.I am needing a scaling animation which shrinks and grows of which i am having code but the issue is the smoothness.Is there any possible way that i can make my animation smoother for scaling animation or any way which shows like the animation appears smoother?>
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the manifest under application tag add this - android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar issue with abrupt animations. Actually, the problem is not with the refresh rate of the device, the application might not be using the full hardware capabilities of the Android device, so not much can really be done

Also add the following line in the application tag of the manifest  `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to ensure HW acceleration is used

Comment: I already tried that,still no luck.can we make it appear like it is smooth for scaling animation(Shrink and grow)?

Comment: Yes, In my application the Shrink and Grow animation got smoother after adding the above line.

Comment: I am sorry but after adding android:hardwareAccelerated="true" made no changes to the animation.Is there any other alternative or atleast make it appear smoother?

Comment: Animation anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.shrink_grow);
imageview.startanimation(anim);